# Visual Studio 2022 CodeLens

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

CodeLens has stopped working in my Enterprise version of VS2022. It shows "- references" in the references section in any class that I open. I have tried the following on my solution and still no joy:

- Updated to the latest version
- Restarted the app
- Restarted the machine
- switched off CodeLens and back on again
- The same as above but include a restart of VS2022
- The same as above but restarting the machine in between times
- Thrown the machine out the window (not really but nearly!!!)

Am at my wits end because I use it a lot with this large app. Does anyone have any pearls of wisdom that may help get my CodeLens back working???

Comment: Did you try fixing/reinstalling VS?

Answer (score 3):

There's another way to navigate to the references - put the cursor on/in the name of the item and press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (I believe this is the default). This will open up the Find results window with all the references to the item.

If you haven't tried reinstalling Visual Studio I would give that a go too but this should work until you have time to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently installed any new extensions?

I had the same problem after installing **AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2022**.

I tried all the above troubleshooting steps save for completely reinstalling Visual Studio, but when I removed the new extension the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To enable CodeLens in Visual Studio OR to display reference information directly above code elements:

```
In Visual Studio,
1. Go to the "Tools" menu
2. Select "Options"
3. In the "Options" window, navigate to "Text Editor" > "All Languages" > "CodeLens"
4. Check the box "Enable CodeLens"
```

This will enable CodeLens. When you hover over a method or property, Visual Studio might display a small indicator with the number of references above the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try delete all files in %temp% and restart VS2022 and toggle Codelens options.

This worked for me.